# Embed watermark with CSS

Tags: css, watermark

I have put the following code:

```
<a class="lightbox tSixty cboxElement" href="http://blabla/embed/5346/" rel="pic">
<img class="lightbox" src="http://blabla/thumbs/175x140/r/files/1324542705/00.jpg">
<img style="border: medium none; height: 39px; left: -62px; position: relative; top: -5px; width: 55px;" src="/images/360_view_icon.png">
</a>
```

My problem is, that the 2nd `img` is supposed to be a watermark on the 1st `img`.

It is working, however the width of the `a` element also includes the watermark, hence pushing all the elements on its right by the size of the watermark.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
a{
    position:relative;
}

.watermark{
    position:absolute;
    right:62px;
    bottom:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second `<img>` give `position:absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;` (you can change the position) and the `<a>` tag, give `position: relative;`